# why android workmanager setInitialDelay not working?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I would like to delay the task for a while before starting, but it's not working, always runs immediately.

```kotlin
val myWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<MyWork>()
   .setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build()
```

I write and test my app on the real machine and frequently install the modified app via Android Studio, but I don't want the background tasks to run frequently.

> While the example illustrates how to set an initial delay for a OneTimeWorkRequest, you can also set an initial delay for a PeriodicWorkRequest. In that case, only the first run of your periodic work would be delayed.

This is taken from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/getting-started/define-work#delayed_work) and the confusing part is the `first run`.

It seems to me that every time run it through Android Studio on the real machine it should be considered a `first run`.

But the reality is that every time I `run` these scheduled tasks, they are executed immediately.

Comment: `It seems to me that every time run it through Android Studio on the real machine it should be considered a first run.` - no, that's not correct. You'd need to 'Clear Data' or completely uninstall and reinstall your app for it to be a first run. What makes you think it should be considered a first run?

Comment: @ianhanniballake everytime `reinstall your app` make me think it's first run. If this is not, then how should I make it run with a delay?